# Battery Tester Circuit with 3 LEDS

Tags: logic-gates, low-power, comparator, indicator, low-battery

I'm designing a small system that uses an ATMEGA328P and a LoRa module that runs on 3.3V using a AAA 1.5V battery. The battery is connected to a Boost Converter which steps up the 1.5V to 3.3V to power the entire system. So obviously the whole system needs to have a low power consumption to save battery power. I want to attach a push button in the circuit that displays the battery level when pressed through LEDs.

The LED indicators are as follows.

- Green LED  - V_Bat > 1.4V
- Yellow LED - 0.9V < V_Bat < 1.4V
- Red LED    - V_Bat < 0.9V

Here is the design of my circuit using the following components

- Voltage Regulator - [TPS61221DCKT](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps61221.pdf)
- SCHOTTKY Diode - [STPS1L30A](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1690210.pdf?_ga=2.15688118.1000179908.1529915639-1130168146.1528125423&_gac=1.117373428.1529980841.Cj0KCQjwpcLZBRCnARIsAMPBgF0DPmucOlE47miCQc5eYBwLNtjK9s37BTIHorPiOIfHhJykpmBbjtwaAnSMEALw_wcB)
- Analog Comparator - [TSX393IYDT](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2259183.pdf?_ga=2.28203388.1738858970.1530497141-1130168146.1528125423&_gac=1.228972910.1529980841.Cj0KCQjwpcLZBRCnARIsAMPBgF0DPmucOlE47miCQc5eYBwLNtjK9s37BTIHorPiOIfHhJykpmBbjtwaAnSMEALw_wcB)
- XOR Logic Gates   - [74AC86SC](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2304239.pdf?_ga=2.43821349.1000179908.1529915639-1130168146.1528125423&_gac=1.119993722.1529980841.Cj0KCQjwpcLZBRCnARIsAMPBgF0DPmucOlE47miCQc5eYBwLNtjK9s37BTIHorPiOIfHhJykpmBbjtwaAnSMEALw_wcB)
- Green LED - [KP-2012LSGC](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1854080.pdf?_ga=2.204305744.1738858970.1530497141-1130168146.1528125423&_gac=1.181801301.1529980841.Cj0KCQjwpcLZBRCnARIsAMPBgF0DPmucOlE47miCQc5eYBwLNtjK9s37BTIHorPiOIfHhJykpmBbjtwaAnSMEALw_wcB)
- Orange LED - [KPT-2012LVSECK-J4-PRV](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2068431.pdf?_ga=2.204305744.1738858970.1530497141-1130168146.1528125423&_gac=1.181801301.1529980841.Cj0KCQjwpcLZBRCnARIsAMPBgF0DPmucOlE47miCQc5eYBwLNtjK9s37BTIHorPiOIfHhJykpmBbjtwaAnSMEALw_wcB)
- Red LED - [KPT-2012LVSECK-J3-PRV](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2068430.pdf?_ga=2.204305744.1738858970.1530497141-1130168146.1528125423&_gac=1.181801301.1529980841.Cj0KCQjwpcLZBRCnARIsAMPBgF0DPmucOlE47miCQc5eYBwLNtjK9s37BTIHorPiOIfHhJykpmBbjtwaAnSMEALw_wcB)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQUWLK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here are my questions.

1. Will the circuit work?
2. Will the components I picked out worked? (I picked components that are all low power)
3. Are there any necessary resistors or passive components needed in the circuit to limit current anywhere?
4. In my voltage divider, how high can I set the resistors to reduce power consumption before it starts giving problem?
5. Any suggestions to improve the circuit?

Thanks for the help in advance and sorry for the many questions

Comment: That will very likely work fine. However, since an ATMEGA328 is already there, I would just connect the battery to an analog input and write some code that does the measurement when you press the button (also connected to the ATMEGA328). This of course assumes that you still have some pins left on the ATMEGA.

Comment: Thanks, that was actually my backup-plan. However, I'm trying to avoid using the ATMEGA as it will require it to wakeup from sleep mode and run a code which will cause it to draw more power.

Comment: if you use common anode red-green LED you only need two comparators, (and no gates) but you'll annoy the colour-blind.

Comment: nice circuit  - simple and elegant if you don't mind the component count. But - where the output of the switch goes to XOR2, the vertical wire - are those nodes to the battery output? Looks like a diagram error. That shorts the battery to the 3.3V.

Comment: *which will cause it to draw more power* If you'd use an interrupt to wake up the ATMEGA you can let it sleep until the button is pressed. In my view if using the ATMEGA for this uses more power than the comparator solution, you're doing the ATMEGA solution wrong.

Comment: @dmb is right, the dots should not be there! Also, I see another issue (yes even though I said it looked fine) there will be a current flowing into the inputs of the comparators when they have no supply voltage! This current is caused by the ESD diodes between inputs and supply pins. You should be **very careful** when applying a voltage to chips that do not have a supply voltage! See the EEVBlog video about this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2yFh7Vv0Paw&t=3s  and yes that applies to **all chips** not only micros.

Comment: well spotted Bimpelrekkie. This could be solved by using a 2 pole switch, and switching both Vbat and 3V3.

Comment: even then you might have issues if the switch pole with Vbat closed a bit before 3V3 . A diode to ensure that Vbat is never more than 0.7V above 3V3 would be wise. Otherwise you might get annoying chip failures every now and again. I will add an answer with a sketch so you can see what I mean.

Comment: I could be mistaken, but if I remember correctly the discharge curve of a AAA is almost flat for most of the graph, meaning that apart from the beginning and end the voltage probably won't change that much. Therefor it will be quite tricky to get accurate readings. Will it be a crude indication on if the battery is full, empty or somewhere between 20 and 80% sure. But if you want something more accurate you might need a different approach.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Regarding the power consumption, correct me if I'm wrong. The ATMEGA328P uses about 5mA when active running on 8MHz at 3.3V, whereas based on the datasheets of this circuit the components only use about 40uA when active. In addition to that, the LoRa module in my circuit will be connected two the only two interrupt pins of the ATMEGA328P.
Secondly, thanks for spotting the mistake in the diagram I have corrected it.

Comment: @RemcoVink Based on my research, the discharge graph changes significantly based on different type of batteries but there are quite a lot which stays steady for most of its capacity. However, I couldn't find any other simple way of measuring the battery level, do you know any that you could recommend?

Comment: *ATMEGA328P uses about 5mA when active running on 8MHz at 3.3V* That's true **however** it will not be running in that mode all the time. It might be in that mode for say 10 ms after you press the button. The rest of the time it will be in sleep mode. If you account for that then current consumption is **much** lower than 5 mA. I made a gadget which shortly wakes up every 8 seconds, it lasts at least a year on 2 AA batteries. On average power consumption is ledd than 50 uA I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks good but there is a problem as spotted by @Bimpelrekkie above -  the comparator inputs always have volts applied, which means they will draw current and may fail as you violate the max ratings at the input.

This modification should correct those problems:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flAAOu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now the circuit is completely isolated when the (double pole) switch is not pressed. The diode protects the comparator inputs, given that the two poles of the switch will not close at exactly the same time.

Comment: Strictly speaking, adding the DPST switch and diode does not satisfy the data sheet requirement that the input voltage never exceed the supply voltage...you still have the inputs above the supply voltage by a diode's forward voltage. I think in this case you can just add a 10k resistor between the battery and the comparators to limit the current that flows through the internal ESD diodes. I'll admit that the datasheet doesn't appear to give any guaranteed options here.

Comment: or simply scan around for another comparator that is a bit more understanding. I think it's worth making this circuit work, it has the great benefit of simplicity.

Comment: Thanks for the circuit @dmb. I can use a low forward voltage diode of about 0.3V and attach the 10k resistor as recommended by Elliot Alderson. This should only cause the supply voltage to be higher than the input by a small amount for a short time. If I have to look for another comparator, what should I be looking for in its datasheet?

Comment: You're welcome. Look for absolute max ratings for voltage on  the + and - inputs. Ideally you want one that can take Vcc + 0.7V (as well as being able to operate at 3V3 of course). If you use a schottky diode instead of 1N4148, you can drop that to Vcc + 0.3V or so.

Comment: I have redesigned the schematic based on your recommendations and I have re-pick the comparator. Based on this comparator datasheet, it states that the input voltage may exceed the supply voltage as long as its within the common-mode voltage. I also picked a diode with low a forward voltage and put the selected LEDs for the circuit. My only concern now is, if the op-amp can supply enough current to light up the green LED.

Comment: what is specified as the maximum output current? You need a minimum of about 1mA.

Comment: @dmb it specifies maximum output current at 20mA, but the High Level Output Current says 1nA. So I'm not sure which to look at.

Comment: @dmb I just realise I have another problem though. I can't seem to find a momentary tactile switch that is DPST. From some research it seems like it may not exist. Do you think its possible to attach a transistor or a MOSFET to activate the battery voltage? Or is there any other component i can use? This device has to be small as its suppose to fit in a small key enclosure.

Comment: you probablt could do it with MOSFET's but I would likely make a proto on stripboard first as it might take a bit of tweaking to make it work right.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you will get enough current to illuminate your LEDs. The comparator datasheet specifies that the output voltage will be at least 1.8V when sourcing 4mA. That same 4mA passing through 150\$\Omega\$ will drop an additional 0.6V so you may not even get your green LED to light up. This circuit might work as a one-off hack if you omit the resistors and use low current LEDs but I wouldn't use it for a mass-produced product.

I don't think you need the XOR gates. The top comparator's output would go to the green LED's anode, as you have shown. Connect the yellow LED's anode to the output of the bottom comparator and its cathode to the output of the top comparator. Connect the red LED's anode to the 3.3V supply and its cathode to the output of the bottom comparator. Suitable current limiting resistors will be needed, of course.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fU8FYA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This answer is objectively wrong and speculative.

Comment: @JoeS Your comment is unsubstantiated and valueless. So educate me. Correct my reading of the datasheet and Ohm's law calculations.

Comment: I actually like this circuit also and would like to know what @JoeS means by that it wont work.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Sorry if this is a stupid question as I'm not very familiar  with powering LEDs direct from logic gates. Which part of the datasheet did you see that it states minimum voltage 1.8V? How I calculated the values were by assuming my LEDs use around 5mA with a forward voltage of 1.8V since they are only indicator LEDs. Then from the datasheet it says VOH is 2.56V running at 24mA. So based on that I calculated the resistor to be about 150 ohms. Is this wrong?

Comment: @Max Your green LED runs directly off of the comparator, so you need to use the \$V_{OH}\$ for that component. I was mistaken to say that the red LED wouldn't light, it is the green. Oh, and you get 12mA from the '86 when used at 3V. It's hard to say if the resistor values are correct without data on the LEDs.

Comment: I have reselected the comparator to suit the requirements of the input voltage. I have also selected the low power LEDs that I will be using for the system that operates at 2mA with an average forward voltage of 1.9V. Based on the new comparator datasheet, it says it has an output current of 20mA but at the bottom, the IOH is 1nA which seems awfully low. So I'm not entirely sure which value should I be looking at.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the LM3914 (or similar) that is designed for this sort of application -

[image]

There are lots of examples in the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3914.pdf)

You could obviously modify an example to just have 3 LEDs.